# How to create database in existing RDS instance using terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform to create RDS instance

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "postgresql" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  engine               = "postgres"
  engine_version       = "14.1"
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  username             = var.db_username
  password             = var.db_password
  publicly_accessible  = false
}
```

note that `db_name` attribute is not included so this configuration will not create any database

Is there anyway to create empty database using terraform in existing RDS instance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [postgresql_database](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs/resources/postgresql_database) to create a database in your rds belonging to [postgresql](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs) provider.